# DJANGO default/error url

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

Is there a way for an url in django to be triggered when no pattern matched the url requested by the client, something like:

`defaulturl = "/path/to/default/page"`

`errorpage = "/path/to/error/page"`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should create

> 404.html

file inside your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` path

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You do it with django inbuilt or custom handler.

In urls.py

```
from app.error_view import my_custom_404_view #app is actually your app name

handler404 = my_custom_404_view
```

and in error_view.py define method my_custom_404_view

```
> def my_custom_404_view(request, template_name='404.html'):
>     url_path = request.path_info
>     if not url_path.endswith('/'):
>         url_path = url_path + '/'
>         return http.HttpResponseRedirect(url_path) # its just a example , you can edit whatever you want too. :)
```